# What should I do with a bounty when the answerer has left the site?

Tags: discussion, bounty

A few days ago I asked [a question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9020/what-was-traded-on-the-chicago-board-of-trade-in-the-mid-1800s).  It didn't get any answers, so I started a bounty on it.  A user of this site answered it, but now it looks like they're not on this site anymore (icon is just a grey head, name is generic, no link to profile anymore).

The bounty is still open, and they're the only answerer.  How should I handle the bounty?

Comment: You should be able to award the bounty to the answer.

Comment: @Luke, I *can* award the bounty to the answerer, I'm just not sure whether I *should*.

Comment: @Joe Meh. Personally, I'd just forget about it. Half of it will automatically go to the answer (because it's upvoted). The only good thing that might come of the bounty right now is that it might perhaps inspire another answer. So, letting it run its full course makes (some) sense.

Comment: On the bright side, you'll get a badge for awarding it. Unfortunately, you've already got that badge.

Answer (score 2):

You should award the bounty to the user. Yes it will be wasted, but in your personal estimation that is where the bounty should go. Reputation does not necessarily need to stay with active users.